# JavaFX -- what is rationale for Events vs Property Changes

Tags: javafx, clojure, color-picker

Using JavaFX 8 and Clojure, I've put a `ChangeListener` on the `valueProperty` of a `ColorPicker`.  I also put an `Eventhandler` with `setOnAction`.

This is pretty cool.  It allows me to watch the color values change as the cursor moves around the palette.  When the cursor moves around the palette, I get a bunch of `ChangeListener` stuff as the `valueProperty` changes, but I only get an `Event` when the color is finally chosen.

The question is:
What is the philosophy behind when a control emits an `Event` vs. just letting the user watch for changes?

```
(let [cp (ColorPicker.)]
  (.setOnAction cp (eventhandler [e] (println "event: "(.getValue cp))))
  (add-listener! cp :value
                 (change-listener [_ obs old new]
                                  (println "change-listener:" old new)))
  (.show (make-node-window cp)))
```

Comment: This question doesn't seem to have much to do with Clojure, but actually only concerns JavaFx.  Perhaps removing the Clojure tag will get you an answer.  But yes, it is cool. (I use JavaFX in Clojure myself.)